# Spring boot @Async is not working at some places

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Configuration with EnableAsync exists, @Async working great from @RestController, but nested call, when I'm trying to call from my services BatchLogGateway#writeBatchLog(), Spring executing INSERT in same thread, I see "ASYNC-xxx" thread number in Spring logs.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ThreadConfig {

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(60);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(200);
        //other proeprties to be set here
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("ASYNC-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class BatchLogGateway {
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchLogGateway.class);

    @Async
    public void writeBatchLog(int batchNo, String errorTxt) {
        MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        namedParameters.addValue("batchNo", batchNo);
        namedParameters.addValue("error", errorTxt);
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO batches_error_log (error_log, batch_no) values (:error, :batchNo)", namedParameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("writing into batchLog {} was unsuccessful", batchNo);
        }
    }
}
```

Spring boot 3.1.2, jdk 20.

Comment: Nested calls from the same class will not work asynchronously using Async annotation. The call must come from another class.

Comment: Yes, writeBatchLog() the only method in the BatchLogGateway service and calls come from separated BatchGateway service

Comment: Is BatchGateway also annotated as Spring component? And with auto-wired BatchLogGateway?

Comment: Yes,  BatchGateway annotated as Service, the only nuance -   BatchGateway use BatchLogGateway only if business logic service catch exception and stacktrace need to be written. But all beans in call chain are Spring components and marked as Service

Comment: Please share the relevant code where you call the async method. Not just the pseudo code.